# java.net.SocketException : read time out- Android Exception

Tags: android, sockets, android-emulator

java.net.SocketException : read time out

I am trying to communicate with devices from android tablet using socket.

If device is connected on right port and i send the command it works fine. but if i remove the device and sent the command to the socket, during socket connection instead of ConnectionRefused Exception (tested on core java program) it waits for approx 1 min and then send SocketTimeoutException.

Can anyone clarify me that why its happening becoz on one activity i am handling 4 devices if one of the device is not connecten then no device will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection is not actually refused. Your `Socket` tries to connect to a device which is not there but the address is valid, so the `SocketTimeoutException`.

Comment: Yes device is not connected, but why android dont  throw the same exception which java 6 throw. I am using same JDK for android and simple program.

Comment: Well, it can either be implementation dependant or just tied to the way the systems use the network interface.

Comment: Hmmm, i am not able to figure out it properly...Thanks anyways.